Piano music brackets
What do these brackets mean under the groups notes?

I found this on MuseScore.

Those brackets are pedal markings.
In this case, they mean: Apply the sustain pedal (the rightmost pedal) at the start of each measure, hold it down throughout, and release at the end of each measure.

Another style of pedal marking uses a “Ped.” symbol (in a fancy font) to mark the start point, and an asterisk-like “*” symbol to mark the release point.

There's going to be some nasty clashes, particularly in bars 13 and 15, if those are takes as pedal markings!

There's also a hybrid notation using ‘Ped.’ to depress the pedal, but then lines such as in the question showing how long to hold and when to release it.  (It's a shame we don't see the first page in the question; it would be perfectly clear if the first line started with a ‘Ped.’.)

@gidds You can see the first page if you follow the link.

Ask the person who wrote it!   What's the source?
They aren't standard notation.  I suppose they might be an attempt to show pedalling but, considering the musical content, they really shouldn't be!
{EDIT}  I see MuseScore DOES offer these as sustain pedal markings.   Odd!
The rhythmic groupings suggest that this wasn't scored by someone who knew a lot about notation.  Or music, really.

When MuseScore is the source, anything goes.

They're unlikely to show anything but pedalling, but what a mess!

Mmm.  It's also not obvious how you'd cover all those left-hand notes without e.g. rolling the chords.  (Assuming it's intended to be played by a solo pianist, as it seems.)
